# How to pass an external/custom parameter to a test script in PLAYWRIGHT and get it on a custom reporter generated report

Tags: typescript, automation, automated-tests, playwright, playwright-test

Hi everyone I just want to find out a way to add an external parameter(Like test case id of the related test case) to a test script and passed it to a custom reporter generated report.

I tried something like this but I need a fixed way to do this.
[test script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0D8y.jpg)
[custom reporter class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWx6h.jpg)

Comment: Please see [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)